# Equivalent R function to slackr_upload for microsoft teams

Tags: r, slack, microsoft-teams

We have recently moved from slack to Microsoft teams. There was a useful function (`slackr`) that allowed for files to be uploaded to slack from R (example below) and so wondering if there is an equivalent for Microsoft teams.

```
library(slackr)

slackrSetup(incoming_webhook_url = "webhook-url",
            api_token = "api-token")

d1 <-
  data.frame(col1 = "a", col2 = "b")

write.table(
  d1,
  file = paste0("my-location/export.csv"))

slackr_upload(paste0("my-location/export.csv"),
              channel = "my-channel")
```

I have found that there is a `teamr` function which is useful for messages, but doesn't allow uploading of files. I have attempted to at least format the contents of the dataframe as a table in markdown in the message sent from `teamr`, but as the tables can be quite large (500 rows, 20-30 columns) this isn't convenient for the Microsoft teams users to extract the data.

Alternatively, I can create and send an email with an attachment from R, but hoping there is an approach to keep it to teams that I have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Gakku said I think that could be achieved with `Microsoft365R` package.

I think something in line this would put it in specific team, even specific channel creating upload folder along the way

```
library(Microsoft365R)  
team <- get_team("NAME OF YOUR TEAM")  
channel <- team$get_channel("NAME OF YOUR CHANNEL")   
channel$get_folder()$create_folder("UPLOAD LOCATION")  
channel$get_folder()$get_item("UPLOAD LOCATION")$upload("UPLOAD_FILE.CSV")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case someone comes across this, look at [microsoft365r](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R) which lets you upload files and much more in MS teams.